# API for fetching incidents on specific alert policy

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find the API to get the incident for a specific alert policy that I created on GCP. I'm able to get emails when the threshold is reached, but I couldn't find a way to fetch that incident using **[postman][1]**. I found the API to get the policy that I created on GCP, but not for incident generated. Any help is appreciated.

Edited: The Json response that i get for the alert Policy API ([https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/{projectId}/alertPolicies/{alertId}](https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/alertPolicies/%7BalertId%7D)) looks like this

{
"name": "projects/{projectId}/alertPolicies/{alertId}",
"displayName": "Max Memory Utilization on a Node",
"combiner": "OR",
"creationRecord": {
"mutateTime": "2021-03-02T18:05:21.054509916Z",
"mutatedBy": "myemail"
},
"mutationRecord": {
"mutateTime": "2021-08-09T16:24:50.941114533Z",
"mutatedBy": "myemail"
},
"conditions": [
{
"conditionThreshold": {
"filter": "resource.type = "gce_instance" AND metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/guest/memory/bytes_used"",
"comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
"thresholdValue": 5,
"duration": "0s",
"trigger": {
"count": 1
},
"aggregations": [
{
"alignmentPeriod": "60s",
"perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN",
"crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_MAX",
"groupByFields": [
"metric.label.instance_name"
]
}
]
},
"displayName": "Memorystore Memcached Node - Memory usage [MAX]",
"name": "projects/{projectId}/alertPolicies/{alertId}/conditions/14902542656838734365"
}
],
"notificationChannels": [
"projects/{projectId}/notificationChannels/17463875491346552338"
],
"enabled": true,
"alertStrategy": {}
}

but this is just policy

Comment: What's the content of the request (header and body) and the response in postman?

Comment: i have edited my question to include the json response that i get for the alert policy, but i don't need policy. i need an api that shows me all the alerts that occurred, you can call them incidents , due to this alert policy i posted on the top.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're trying to record the triggering of an alerting policy by using Postman. You can actually achieve this by using the [monitoring system](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events) offered by GCP.

The linked documentation gives you a guidance on how you can view and manage incidents for metric-based alerting policies. It also gives you an approach on how to both filter the incidents and find older ones. Please, comment bellow if this has helped you.

Comment: I have already saw that documentation for navigating around inside GCP, but that's not what i'm looking for. i need to fetch the incidents using api for specific alert policy. I'm able to get those alerts on my email but couldn't find a way to fetch them using postman. on the documentation there is a part that shows how to use the api for managing the alert policies ( https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/{project-id}/alertPolicies/{alert-id}). Is there an api for incidents because i couldn't find one.

Comment: Can anyone share an API that fetches incidents for specific alert policy? i need an api that might look like , monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects{project-id}/alertPolicies/{alert-id}/incident/{incident-id} . i can't find any API on the documentation that allows me to fetch the generated alerts that i get on my emails. Please help.

Comment: While I go and search through the documentation (found this: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-replace-channels), have you given a look to BindPlane? As a replacement to Postman.

Comment: Thank you @MariCruzR for your effort to help me. So Im working on a code that consumes json retrieved from those GCP incidents. i can get the alert policy which i found on the documentation but not for the alerts raised. So, i can only use java code only. :)

Comment: any idea is appreciated :)

Comment: i don't think that Google exposes a direct API that enables you to fetch generated Alerts.